# How to login to Linux created using Azure with username and password

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

**What I want to do:**

- I want to make an SSH connection and log in to Linux, which was created using Azure, as a user named testuser.

**Problem:**

- I get the following error when I run the ssh command.

```
C:\Users\avduser>ssh testuser@<IP address>
testuser@<IP address>: Permission denied(publickey).
```

- /var/log/auth.log

```
Connection reset by authenticating user testuser <IP address> port <portNum> [preauth]
```

**I tried: **

- change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

- service restart: `systemctl restart sshd`
- virtial Machine restart: `reboot`

I don't have any other ideas to try.
Thank you

Comment: Try from another network, if you are trying to access from any corporate network.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don’t use corporate network..

Answer (score 0):

Given the steps you've already taken and the persistent issue, let's explore additional solutions and troubleshooting steps to resolve the `Permission denied (publickey)` error when trying to SSH into your Linux VM in Azure as `testuser`. I feel it has something to do with the pem keys. However better to verify   all the other aspects as well.
Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and confirm there's only one `PasswordAuthentication yes` directive and it's not commented out. After making changes, remember to restart the SSH service (`sudo systemctl restart sshd`). Ensure the `testuser` exists and has a valid password set. Having said that.

In order to login to a linux machine on azure there are two ways-

1. using SSH
2. Using password

Using SSH-
Create your Linux VM as usual on Azure.
[image]

Just select SSH public key. As go proceed, Azure will prompt you to download this pem key which you just created. Download and save it to your desired location and continue to complete the setup process. Once the VM is ready, go to resource and connect.
[image]
Post validation, it will ask you to connect. Now it's your choice if you want to connect via azure cli or your own native ssh for example powershell. Here just do
`ssh -i ~/<yourpath-where-you-downloaded-the-pemfile>/<Your-Key-Name.pem> <username>@20.127.229.58`[image]

Second option, using password.
Same process as above just during creation select password instead of ssh and give your preferred password.
[image]

Rest of the configuration will remain same, but here azure won't prompt you for downloading the pem key as you have set password. Just connect once the system is ready.
Do a `su <username>`
[image]

Reference:
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-portal?tabs=ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have opened `etc/ssh/sshd_config` and confirmed that there is only one `PasswordAuthentication yes` and it is not commented out. I also restarted the SSH service(`sudo systemctl restart sshd`) after making the change.
I was able to log into Linux with azureuser and then switch to testuser using the password, so I also checked that testuser existed and had a valid password set.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/50-cloud-init.conf` was included in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and did not rewrite this value.

- For password authentication, I need to edit the following values

  - `etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf`(only Debian / Ubuntu)

    - `PasswordAuthentication no`
  - `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

    - `PasswordAuthentication yes`
- For keyboard-interactive authentication, I need to edit the following values

  - `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

    - `KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes`